# C++ - Convert LPSTR to const char* in MinGW under Windows

Tags: c++, windows, char, mingw, lpstr

I'm having trouble converting from LPSTR to const char* in MinGW under Windows.

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
  DIR *dir;
  struct dirent *ent;
  LPSTR buffer;
  GetCurrentDirectory(100, buffer);
  const char *str = *buffer;
  dir = opendir(*str);
  return 0;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is grab a list of all the current files in a directory and write it to a file; I can do the latter, but the former is giving me some trouble. I can figure out how to read the directory once I can convert the different variable types.

I know what LPSTR is, but I don't know how to apply it to this code.

Do not suggest using `atlbase.h` because MinGW does not support it, and I'm not willing to go back to Visual unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be a bit confused about indirection.  `LPSTR` is a `char*`.  It is a pointer to a `char` (or, as is the case here, a pointer to the initial element of an array of `char`).

When you call `GetCurrentDirectory`, you need to pass it a pointer to the initial element of an array of `char` and the size of that array.  So, what you need to do is declare an array and pass that into the function.  For example,

```
char buffer[MAX_PATH];
GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, buffer);
```

With your current implementation, your program will assuredly crash because `buffer` is uninitialized, so `GetCurrentDirectory` will attempt to write to some random location in memory.

You should also check the return value of `GetCurrentDirectory` to ensure that it completed successfully and that the buffer contains the complete path.  [Its documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364934%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) explains the values that it may return.

Once you have the path, you can pass it directly to `opendir`:  the array `buffer` is implicitly convertible to a pointer to its initial element--that is, the `char[MAX_PATH]` can be converted to a `char*`--and that `char*` can be implicitly converted to the `char const*` required by `opendir`:

```
DIR* dir = opendir(buffer);
```

Do note that the signature of `GetCurrentDirectory` depends on whether the `UNICODE` macro is defined or not:  if you are compiling your program for Unicode, it actually takes a pointer to an array of `wchar_t`.  If you build a Unicode program, you will need to account for this (you *should* use Unicode if you can).

Comment: Ah, thanks anyway. It seems MinGW lacks a few features that Visual has, so I may need to switch over or look for a workaround. Regardless, I appreciate the help.

Comment: @user You should be able to define the `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` symbols to compile Unicode applications even in MinGW. It still uses the standard Windows headers, and this is how they work. Of course, you'll need to use the `wchar_t` type instead of `char` for characters and strings.